# Mouse Cursor flickering in Popos (Ubuntu 20.04 )

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, xrandr, pop-os

I started using a second Monitor alongside my laptop's monitor, since then the pointer of my mouse started blinking, `(appears and disappears very fast)` which is annoying. Some answers to similar questions suggest disabling unknown monitors, but I don't have any. Any suggestion to what might the problem ?
[monitor-1-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD68o.png)
[monitor-2-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFhSu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also noticed the same proplema (I have a new dell XPS plus with 3840x2400 resolution, so similar to yours). The problem arises when enabling Fractional scaling to adapt displays with different resolutions.
First of all turn off Fractional scaling, unplug the secondary monitor and copy and make executable (save wherever you want) the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 

RESULT=`xrandr | grep -w DP*`

if [[ "$RESULT" =~ " connected " ]]; then
 DP_LINE=`xrandr | grep -w DP* | grep -w connected`
 DP_NUMBER=`echo "$DP_LINE" | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d':' -f1`
# echo $DP_NUMBER
 xrandr --output $DP_NUMBER --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x0
 xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.9999x0.9999
fi
    
exit 0
```

Then connect the secondary monitor, and run the script. Flickering should be eliminated..

PS - I wrote the code on the fly and the part inside the if can certainly be improved

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my computer: Ubunto 22.04.2 (jammy) and two monitors (my laptop and a dell 24 inches. The laptop resolutions was 2880 x 1620 (16:9) and the dell monitor was 1920 x 1080 (16:9). The problem was really annoying. I change the laptop resolution to 1920 x 1080 and 125% scale. The other monitor I did nothing and I have the mouse cursor as normal.